# Get values from multiple RadioGroups

Tags: android, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I am creating an activity which contains **7 RadioGroups** each with **5 RadioButtons**. My problem is that I am getting selected index of only one RadioGroup (lvl_mon) and the other 6 are returning -1 however they are selected. My code is :

```
lvl_mon = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.lvl_monday);
lvl_tue = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.lvl_tuesday);
lvl_wed = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.lvl_wednesday);
lvl_thu = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.lvl_thursday);
lvl_fri = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.lvl_friday);
lvl_sat = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.lvl_saturday);
lvl_sun = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.lvl_sunday);

int index_mon = lvl_mon.indexOfChild(findViewById(lvl_mon.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));
int index_tue = lvl_tue.indexOfChild(findViewById(lvl_tue.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));
int index_wed = lvl_wed.indexOfChild(findViewById(lvl_wed.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));
int index_thu = lvl_thu.indexOfChild(findViewById(lvl_thu.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));
int index_fri = lvl_fri.indexOfChild(findViewById(lvl_fri.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));
int index_sat = lvl_sat.indexOfChild(findViewById(lvl_sat.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));
int index_sun = lvl_sun.indexOfChild(findViewById(lvl_sun.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem , I had same ids of RadioButtons in each RadioGroup so I changed the ids plus cleaned the project. This fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

If you have buttons inside of your radio groups then you can do the following:

```
RadioGroup lvl_mon = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.lvl_monday);
String selected_mon = ((RadioButton) findViewById(lvl_mon .getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();
```

Comment: but I want the index of RadioButton in RadioGroup

Comment: the problem is I am getting index from first radiogroup but other are returning -1 though they are selected

Comment: make sure you're using different ids for each radio button

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this

```
lvl_mon = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.lvl_monday);
RadioButton lvl_mon1;

     lvl_mon.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           lvl_mon1= (RadioButton)findViewById(checkedId);

           switch(checkedId){
           case R.id.radio0:
              // do somthings
           break;

           case R.id.radio1:
           .......

          }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int radioButtonID = radioButtonGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
View radioButton = radioButtonGroup.findViewById(radioButtonID);
int idx = radioButtonGroup.indexOfChild(radioButton);
```

This may help!!

Comment: isn't it the same as what I am doing ?

Comment: You want to get the index of selected radio button of radio group at run time. right?

Comment: Try with getting at run time on checked changed event ... as well log it.. so, you will get exact idea. I am developing same type of application and faced the same -1 index.

Comment: I figured out the problem. I was having same ids for RadioButtons in each RadioGroup. I have changed the id of each RadioButton plus cleaned the project